# ntpq does not print the list of the peers immediately

Tags: freebsd, ntp, ntpd

I'm on FreeBSD. I used from a cisco router as the server and my system as the client.
I used `ntp` to sync the clock between server and client. It worked and the clock has synced but when I run `ntpq -p`, it shows the correct value after about 5 minute.

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
  12.12.12.1      LOCAL(1)         8 u   33   64  377    0.649   10.050  26.488
```

after 5 min the `12.12.12.1` changed to `*12.12.12.1`.

How can I reduce this time that the `ntpq -p` shows the changes immediatly?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the issue is. What do you mean by "the correct value"? And what "changes" do you want to see?

Comment: @Kusalananda I edited my post.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that `ntpq` is trying to resolve DNS for the name of the NTP peers and that a misconfigured DNS is causing the timeout and delay of 5 minutes.

You can confirm that that's the case by asking it not to resolve DNS, using the `ntpq -np` command (the `-n` flag tells it not to resolve DNS.)

If that's indeed the case, you can then look into why resolving DNS for those IPs is not working (but that's a separate topic, probably deserves a specific question.)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tested `ntpq -np` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @F.M Please specify what "does not work" actually mean.

Comment: To rephrase Filipe Brandenburger's answer: if you have DNS problems and have configured NTP time sources in `/etc/ntp.conf` by names, it might take 5 minutes for `ntpd` to fully start up. But once it has completed startup, you can diagnose it by comparing how much time is taken by `ntpq -p` vs. `ntpq -np`. If `ntpq -p` is slow but `ntpq -np` responds immediately, you'll need to either fix your DNS resolution or replace all time source names in `/etc/ntp.conf` by the respective IP addresses as a work-around. If both `ntpq -p` and `ntpq -np` are slow, the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @telcoM They're both slow.